# Are these two sentences semantically identical?

Tags: meaning, sentence, syntactic-analysis, semantics, sentence-patterns

Are these two sentences semantically identical?

- By using this website, you are certifying that you have read our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy, you are certifying that you understand our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy, and you are certifying that you agree with our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy.
- By using this website, you are certifying that you have read, understand, and agree with our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy.

Comment: This is off-topic because this site is not a substitute for checking your work with another speaker of English.

Comment: @curiousdannii Huh? Any question on here could be asked of another speaker of English...

Comment: Exactly. Most questions on this site should be closed. Only a few deserve the attention of the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically they are identical.